# ODE with complex coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I have to solve the equation:

$\frac{d^{2}z}{dt^{2}}+e^{it}\frac{dz}{dt}+z=0$

And I really don't know how to do that. I tried to substitute the trial solution $z=e^{\lambda t}$, but as it didn't work, I tried $z=e^{i\lambda t}$, but I still can't get any clear solution.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Some solutions are $z(t)=c\cdot(1-ie^{-it})$.

Comment: Did you use a trial solution?

Comment: You can cook up Did's solution this way. Taking a multiple of $e^{-it}$ will make the first and third terms cancel each other while it will make the second term constant. Taking a constant will make the first and second terms zero while it will make the third term constant. By adding these and exploiting linearity you get Did's solutions. Now you can finish the problem using reduction of order.

Comment: This is can be solved series solution, assume we want to solve near $t=0$ (regular  point, or any other point). Let $z(t)=\sum_0^{\infty}{t^n}$, differentiate and substitute in the equation and replacing $e^{it}$ by its corresponding series. After do the dummy steps you should note the obtained recurrence relation contain real and imaginary parts but this can be easily to solve by noting that Re=0 and Im=0

Comment: @mwomath Hmmm, "the obtained recurrence relation" seems quite unsolvable, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

My first answer is suppressed because the method used to get to the particular solution $e^{ie^{it}}e^{-it}$ was a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

This particular solution, combined with another even simpler one : $(ie^{-it}-1)$, already mentioned by Did, leads to the general solution :
$$z=c_1e^{ie^{it}}e^{-it}+c_2(ie^{-it}-1)$$

A short way :

[image]